# Vagrant 1.6.5 windows/chef-client provisioning fails until first user login

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

Vagrant's chef-client provisioning fails until after I use RDP into the VM and login as 'vagrant' user for the first time.

The debug output says:

INFO interface: Machine: error-exit ["Berkshelf::VagrantWrapperError", "VagrantPlugins::CommunicatorWinRM::Errors::WinRMBadExitStatus: The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.\nVagrant assumes that this means thecommand failed!\n\ncmd.exe /c install.bat 11.16.4\n\nStdout from the command:\n\nDownloading Chef 11.16.4 for Windows...\r\nInstalling Chef 11.16.4\r\n\n\nStderr from the command:\n\n"]

Ideally, I could "vagrant destroy" and "vagrant up" back to back without any other steps necessary.

How can I work around this?

I am using:

Vagrant 1.6.5
Chef 11.16.4
Windows 8 (kensykora/windows_81)
Windows 2012 (kensykora/windows_2012_r2_standard)

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the vagrant user to auto-login:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx

Then you can package the modified box instance and use the new box from there on:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html